MLE: plotting NLL profiles for multi-parameters
I'm trying to plot NLL(negative log likelihood) profiles for multi-parameters denoted as A, B, C, D, E, F. All of these parameters are in correlation since they are in the same ODE system.
The following are some approaches that I've considered.
First, I estimated all 6 parameters using MLE method.
Then, using the estimated values as the central values, I set up intervals of ±5% for each parameter. Next, I divided each interval into 3 equal parts. For instance,
interval A = (A_start, A_est, A_end)
interval B = (B_start, B_est, B_end)
interval C = (C_start, C_est, C_end)
interval D = (D_start, D_est, D_end)
interval E = (E_start, E_est, E_end)
interval A = (F_start, F_est, F_end)
And then, to plot an NLL profile of A, I fixed all other parameters as their estimated values and varied the value of A within its interval to calculate the NLL. That is, I calculated the NLL at points like (A0, B_est, C_est, D_est, E_est, F_est), (A_est, B_est, C_est, D_est, E_est, F_est), (A_end, B_est, C_est, D_est, E_est, F_est). Thus the NLL profile of A appeared as a line which has a minimum point.
The point is, is there anything wrong with my idea? I heard that a multi-variable NLL profile should be plotted as a surface, but I don’t know what I need to change or why.
The NLL profiles have to be represented with 6 2D plots. (x-label: parameter, y-label: NLL)
